# How to change a field result from two words to two letters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running the script below and the result of the areaoflaw field is 'Family Law'. However, the application that is reading the output is looking for a two character result. eg. 'family law' should be FL. How can I change the script to do this?

```
declare @s varchar(100)='(FILE';
select clientid
      ,ClientSort as ClientName
      ,'Y' as Enabled
      ,'N' as HIPPA
      ,matternum
      ,case
          when charindex(@s,[description])>0
          then left(cast([description] as varchar(max)),charindex(@s,[description])-1)
          else [description]
       end as MatterName
      ,'Y' as Enable
      ,'N' as HIPPA
      ,areaoflaw
  from matters
 order by Clientid
         ,matterid
;
```

Comment: What are the other possible values? Is it always two words separated by a space? Do you always want the the first letters of those two words?

Answer (score 2):

Add a `CASE` statement. For example,

```
SELECT ....
CASE
WHEN areaoflaw = 'Family Law' then 'FL'
WHEN areaoflaw = 'Admiralty Law' then 'AL'
WHEN areaoflaw = 'Criminal Law' then 'CL'
WHEN areaoflaw = 'Patent Law' then 'PL'
END as areaoflaw....
```

Comment: Thanks, I added the above but getting boolean error. how do I add a join syntax to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the values are all two words, and you always want the initial letters of those words, you can use a simple combination of `substring` and `charindex`:

```
select 
    ...,
    (
        substring(areaoflaw,1,1) + 
        substring(areaoflaw,charindex(' ', areaoflaw)+1, 1) 
    ) as areaoflaw
```

Comment: Thank you so much. How do set this up for the below that are single words?Workers Comp|WC|Y
Criminal|CR|Y
Family Law|FL|Y
Corporate Business|CB|Y
Personal Injury|PI|Y
Litigation|LI|Y
Estate Matters|EM|Y
Miscellaneous|MI|Y
Appeals|AP|Y
Real Estate|RE|Y

Comment: That looks like the two-letter codes are derived differently for each value, so you'd use a `case` statement as in @Robert's answer. Of course, if you have these values stored in a *SQL table*, then you just need a `join`..